# Mailchimp and stripe integration

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up mailchimp and stripe together, I want everytime a user pays they are also added to mailing list. What is the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can ask stripe customer support about this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your still looking for an answer as it has been some time but Zapier has integration available for Stripe and you can do exactly what you are asking. Here's a tutorial, if you have any trouble let me know: https://zapier.com/zapbook/mailchimp/stripe/